# Целесообразность класса для работы с БД MSSQL

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server

Создал специальный вспомогательный класс для соединения и работы с БД.

Целесообразно ли использовать подобный класс, если нет необходимости или опыта работы с `Entity Framework`. Прошу указать на недочеты и сделать прочие замечания.

Сам класс:

```
public class DBHelper
{
        public static string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=<default>;Initial Catalog=<default>;Persist Security Info=<default>;User ID=<default>;Password=<default>";
        public bool connectionOnline = false;
        public SqlConnection sqlConnection = null;
        public DBHelper(string _DataSource, string _InitialCatalog, string _User, string _Password)
        {
                string AssebledConnectionString =
                        "Data Source=" + _DataSource + ";" +
                        "Initial Catalog=" + _InitialCatalog + ";" +
                        "Persist Security Info=True;" +
                        "User ID=" + _User + ";" +
                        "Password=" + _Password;
                connectionOnline = false;
                InitializeConnection(AssebledConnectionString);
        }
        public DBHelper()
        {
                connectionOnline = false;
                InitializeConnection(sqlConnectionString);
        }
        public DBHelper(string sqlCustomConnectionString = null)
        {
                connectionOnline = false;
                InitializeConnection(sqlCustomConnectionString);
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
                this.DisengageConnection();
                sqlConnection = null;
        }
        void InitializeConnection(string sqlCustomConnectionString = null)
        {
                try
                {
                        if ((connectionOnline) || (sqlConnection != null)) return;
                        sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlCustomConnectionString ?? sqlConnectionString);
                        sqlConnection.Open();
                        connectionOnline = true;
                }
                catch
                {
                        connectionOnline = false;
                        //Не удалось соединиться с базой данных
                }
        }
        void DisengageConnection()
        {
                if ((!connectionOnline) || (sqlConnection == null)) return;
                sqlConnection.Close();
                connectionOnline = false;
        }
        public SqlCommand GetStoredProc(string procedureName)
        {
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(procedureName, sqlConnection)
                {
                        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                };
                return sqlCommand;
        }
        public DataSet GetDataSet(SqlCommand sqlCommand)
        {
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                DataSet dsTable = new DataSet();
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dsTable);
                return dsTable;
        }
        public DataTable GetResultTable(SqlCommand sqlCommand, int dataTableNumber = 0)
        {
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
                DataSet dsTable = new DataSet();
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dsTable);
                if ((dsTable.Tables.Count > 0) && (dsTable.Tables.Count - 1 >= dataTableNumber))
                {
                        return dsTable.Tables[dataTableNumber];
                }
                else
                {
                        return new DataTable();
                }
        }        
}
```

Пример использования хранимой процедуры:

```
DBHelper db = new DBHelper();
SqlCommand sqlCommand = db.GetStoredProc("<имя хранимой процедуры>");
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@<имя параметра 1>",<param1_value>);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@<имя параметра 2>",<param2_value>);
//...
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@<имя параметра N>",<paramN_value>);
//далее действия в зависимости от характера хранимой процедуры
//либо простое исполнение
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
//либо получение данных
DataTable dataTable = db.GetResultTable(sqlCommand);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Целесообразно ли использовать подобный класс, если нет необходимости
>   или опыта работы с Entity Framework.

Подобные классы можно использовать если нет **возможности** работы с Entity Framework (например, Вам достался древний проект) или проект совсем совсем простой. 
Хотя в последнем случае это весьма спорно.

Что касается отсутствия опыта, в качестве довода к использованию подобных решений, то это и вовсе ни о чём. Entity Framework, при наличии познаний в области C# и СУБД, достаточно легко освоить самостоятельно.

Что касается самого класса, крайне желательно:

- Упростить внешний интерфейс.

По сути Ваш класс только создаёт подключение и предоставляет доступ к низкоуровневым объектам на его основе. Таким образом даже в Вашем примере почти всю работу нужно всё равно делать руками.

Поэтому нужно либо упростить вызовы методов так чтобы они только на основе имени объекта БД и его параметров возвращали готовый результат сразу, без дополнительных действий. Либо написать класс обёртку наподобие репозитория, который будет решать низкоуровневые задачи.

- Сделать класс более универсальным.

MS SQL это само по себе не плохо. Только, если не ошибаюсь, он никогда не был единственной СУБД для .NET. Кроме того, если раньше он, **возможно**, и мог претендовать на роль своего рода промышленного стандарта, то сейчас ситуация сильно изменилась. Очень многие проекты на C# используют СУБД не от MS и даже не от Oracle (к примеру, PostgreSQL).

Поэтому узкая специализация фреймворка для работы с СУБД (раз уж Вы решились по сути написать свой) хотя и может оказаться преимуществом в "профильных" проектах, но в целом его применение этими проектами и будет ограничено.